# C code gets stuck unless I call printf() function

Tags: c, printf

I have a code that reads text file, tokenizes words in it, then selects only unique words from text, concatenates them and prints them using puts() function.
Here is full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char str_array[100][100];
char output[100];

void concatenate(int index)
{
  // compares output with empty string
  if (!strcmp(output, "")) 
  {
    strcpy(output, str_array[index]);
  }

  else //else existing string is contcatenated
  {
    strcat(output, " "); // add space
    strcat(output, str_array[index]);
  }
}

void unique_selection(char file[])
{
  FILE *F = fopen(file, "r");
  char ch; char str[100];
  int i=0, j=0;

  while ((ch=getc(F)) != EOF) 
  {
    // if space or newline is detected i.e. word is finished
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') 
    {
      //traverse array of strings
      for(int x=0; x<j; x++)
      {
        //if current str is already in array, skip appending
        if (!strcmp(str_array[x], str)) goto ELSE; 
      }
      strcpy(str_array[j], str);
      j++;
    ELSE:
      i=0;
      memset(str, 0, strlen(str));
    }
    else //otherwise chars of a word get appended to string array
    {
      str[i] = ch;
      i++;
    }
  }

  for(int k=0; k<j; k++)
  {
    concatenate(k);
  }
  puts(output);
  fclose(F);
}

int main(void) {
  char file[] = "test.txt";
  //printf("Output:");
  unique_selection(file);
  return 0;
}
```

The code works perfectly, but I came across a weird issue, every time I tried printing the output string (using `puts()` or `printf("%s")` the program would get stuck, similarly to what happens when loop is iterating forever. And weirdly this issue was fixed by putting the printf before the function call. If I remove `puts()` from function, code runs like normal even with or without the printf in `main()`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your `file` doesn't have enough space to store the string with null-terminator. UB as it is.

Comment: The string `"file.txt"` is 9 characters, not 8:  The 8 printable characters plus 1 null byte.  But rather than counting them, which as you've seen is quite error-prone, why not just do `char file[] = "test.txt";`  The compiler will then determine the size for you.

Comment: `ch` is undeclared. It should be an `int`

Comment: @Tom Karzes, seems to be unrelated, I changed the code to char file[] = "test.txt", still same issue

Comment: *"The code works perfectly,... the program would get stuck"* is a bit weird version of "perfect" ;-)

Comment: If your problem is not solved by the suggestions above, then post [mcve].

Comment: @Ach113 Probably, if the first byte after the string happened to contain zero.  But you're also not checking to see if the `open()` call succeeded, so you don't really know if it did.

Comment: How does your code declare `output`?

Comment: @Eugene, I will update the post with full code

Comment: How large is "test.txt"?

Comment: As @Pablo said, `ch` needs to be `int`

Comment: Does `if (!strcmp(output, ""))` do what you want? That says "if the string is empty..."

Comment: @Weather, that is for initializating the output string, that line checks that its empty, and if it is, writes string directly to output using strcpy() instead of strcat()

Comment: @Eugene, same issue regardless of ch being int or char

Comment: Your `concatenate()` function builds a string from all the input words, but it only has the capacity for 99 characters, some of which will be spaces, plus a terminator.  Why concatenate at all?  Why not just print the words you've found directly?

Comment: @B. Shefter just 38 bytes

Comment: When the code gets stuck, does it get stuck before or after printing `output`?

Comment: Looks like a good use of a hash table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you go wrong:

```
else //otherwise chars of a word get appended to string array
{
  str[i] = ch;
  i++;
}
```

When you first enter the main loop, `str` is uninitialized.  That means that when you append characters to `str[i]` there is no terminating null byte at the end of the string.  This causes string functions like `strlen` and `strcpy` to potentially read past the end of the array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can fix this by initializing `str` to all zeros:

```
char str[100] = {0};
```

The `memset` call after copying the string clears it out for subsequent words.

Also, this is not the best use of `goto`:

```
  for(int x=0; x<j; x++)
  {
    //if current str is already in array, skip appending
    if (!strcmp(str_array[x], str)) goto ELSE; 
  }
  strcpy(str_array[j], str);
  j++;
ELSE:
  i=0;
  memset(str, 0, strlen(str));
```

It would be cleaner to set a flag if your search was successful and act on that when you exit the loop:

```
  int found = 0;
  for(int x=0; x<j; x++)
  {
    //if current str is already in array, skip appending
    if (!strcmp(str_array[x], str)) {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    strcpy(str_array[j], str);
    j++;
  }
  i=0;
  memset(str, 0, strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, interestingly I have used exact same code for traversing the file before but have never encountered this problem, thank you!

Comment: @Ach113 That's undefined behavior for you.  In some cases the array might happen to have all zeros to start, in some cases in may have none.

Comment: @B.Shefter that guarantees that '\0' is in the first byte, I'm not sure about what the standard says will be the rest, but I assume that they are undefined?

Comment: @NeilEdelman It works.  When an initializer is present, any bytes not explicitly initialized are implicitly initialized to 0.